# Datatable JS - Ordering Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, datatable, microsoft-edge

I'm working with [Datatable JS](https://datatables.net/) plugin to display some data, there is a column which contains dates and when clicking the top column name element to order the dates, it works fine for me on my machine using Chrome 112.0.5615.138 (Official Build) (64-bit), however on the same page on other machines, the ordering works for a couple of fields mid-way down the table but nowhere else. I tested on Microsoft Edge on my machine and I could replicate the issue.

Is this a know bug with the plugin or is there something that I am missing here? The code does work as it is functiong correctly on my machine but there seems to be some issue with different peoples browsers and with Edge.

I have cleared cache on all machines tested and breakpointed my code to check for issues, there are no logs in the console for any errors either. I have reviewed my code multiple times and all works as it should.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] - a small example showing the DataTable with some sample data. You can provide that as a runnable [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365) in your question. If the example only shows correct sorting, then please also show, in some other way, what the _incorrect_ sorting looks like. Try to show the locales of the machines where the demo works correctly, and where it does not work correctly. For Windows machines, see [here](https://serverfault.com/q/80635).